# Why doesn't the Insert work for me in SQLITE3?

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

when executing the form, the data is not inserting. I have activated SQLITE3 and I am not skipping any type of error.

The `echo` of the **try** is to see what was wrong but nothing. I see everything right. 
Does anyone help me?

```
$username = $_POST['nombre'];
$clave = $_POST['clave'];
$apenom = $_POST['apenom'];

try {
    $bd = new SQLite3("test");
    //preparamos la sentencia
    echo "INSERT INTO usuarios (username,clave,apenom) VALUES ('$username','$clave','$apenom')";
    $bd->exec("INSERT INTO usuarios (username,clave,apenom) VALUES ('$username','$clave','$apenom')");
    /* while ($row = $resultado->fetchArray()) {
        echo "{$row['username']} {$row['clave']} {$row['apenom']} \n";
    } */
} catch (\Throwable $th) {
    echo $th;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an English-only forum. Please either translate your question to English, or repost it to the appropriate version of SO. Looks like Spanish to me? es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Learn to use parameters and you will probably never have this problem again.

Comment: Are you sure your database connection works using just `"test"`? shouldn't that be `"test.sqlite"` or `"test.db"`?

Answer (score 0):

Do take the advice from the comments into account, database security is not something you should 'wing'...

As for a little help on setting up a connection and importantly **debugging** if anything goes wrong so you know what to fix, the following 'skeleton' might help:

```
<?php

try {
    // connect to your database
    $sqlite = new SQLite3('test.db');
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    // if no connection could be established a exception is thrown
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
// your query
$query = '...';
$result = $sqlite->query($query); // result object (FALSE on error)
if (!$result) {
    // query failed for some reason...
    echo $sqlite->lastErrorMsg();
} else {
    // do something with result
}
```